# K8s Go client library fails to find package on go get

Tags: go, kubernetes

We wrote some Go code to talk to our Kubernetes cluster and fetch the IP of a Service exposed. We do it like so:

```
(import "gopkg.in/kubernetes/kubernetes.v1/pkg/client/restclient")
(import kubectl "gopkg.in/kubernetes/kubernetes.v1/pkg/client/unversioned")

 svc, err := c.Services(k8sNS).Get(svcName)
 if err != nil {
   panic(l.Errorf("Could not retrieve svc details. %s", err.Error()))
 }
 svcIP := svc.Status.LoadBalancer.Ingress[0].IP
```

`go get` works fine, and our script executes when we do `go run ...` and everybody is happy. Now, as of yesterday (from the time this question is posted) on the same script - `go get` fails. The error is like so:

```
[09.07.2016 10:56 AM]$ go get
package k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/authentication.k8s.io/install: cannot find package "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/authentication.k8s.io/install" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/authentication.k8s.io/install (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ckotha/godir/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/authentication.k8s.io/install (from $GOPATH)
```

We have not specifically used `authentication` package in our code. Are we importing kubernetes libraries correctly? is there another way to do this ?

`ls` on `$GOPATH/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/` and found this:

```
:~/godir/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis
[09.07.2016 10:53 AM]$ ls
abac  apps  authentication  authorization  autoscaling  batch  certificates  componentconfig  extensions  imagepolicy  OWNERS  policy  rbac  storage
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a package you imported has changed.

You can update existing repositories:

```
go get -u
```

> The -u flag instructs get to use the network to update the named
>   packages and their dependencies.  By default, get uses the network to
>   check out missing packages but does not use it to look for updates to
>   existing packages.

You do use [gopkg.io](http://labix.org/gopkg.in) to pin the version to v1, but I think you want to be more specific, eg, v1.3.6 (EDIT: this won't work because gopkg.in doesn't permit package selectors more specific than the major version.).

Alternatively, a good way to ensure code stays the same is to compile your binary and execute that, instead of using `go run`.

Comment: thanks Mark. I had tried it earlier, in vain. I deleted all k8s.io/ directory structure tried to run my script and it still failed. Some dependency somewhere is referring to `authentication.k8s.io/install` instead of just `authentication/install`